# dc.js grouping dependency

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Hi I'm struggling for a time with this problem in crossfilter/dc.js:

I have a dataset with three categories, which are depending to each other. I would like to visualize them:

- User can select from first categories
- User can select from reduced set from first category in second category
- User can select from reduced set from second category in third category
- The filtering should only have effects towards the sub-category (first -> second, second-> third)

I am trying to find a simple solution for that, but I always struggling messing up the data in the end..

Comment: I didn't found a graphical solution, but I could solve it with this example: [select-example from dc.js team](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/examples/select.html)

Comment: Yeah, it should work the same with bar or row charts. Note that the effects run either way. I think this is simpler and easier to reason about.

Comment: For me, it didn't worked with rowChart - the first chart looked okay, the second and third were messed up and the javascript interpreter fired exceptions. I changed my code using selectMenu, I didn't changed the dimensions and groups and it works just fine now. The positive effect: now it looks even more intuitive.

Comment: Huh maybe there were too many rows or something. Haven't seen that bug. If you can produce a fiddle showing the problem and file an issue that will help. Otherwise, glad the 2.1 selectMenu helps!

Comment: Hi Gordon and thank you for taking care! :-) I created a fiddle [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/7ohfxc27/) the second and third are messed up and in console F12 there are errors.